# How do Germans refer to people without caring about the gender

Tags: noun, gender, politeness, political-correctness

In German, a noun always has its own gender. However, there is a case I don't know.

Suppose that there is a class with many students, both males and females, and then when I want to refer to all students in that class, which word should I use when there are both, males and females and I want to include all of them in only one word, not only plural of "der Student" or the plural of "die Studentin"? Or when I see a name in a student list but I don't know the gender of that student. What should I say or write?

Comment: the first paragraph [here](http://faql.de/pc.html) might be helpfull

Comment: An alle Menschen und Menschinnen hier: übertreibt es nicht!

Comment: Oh my, prepare for truckloads of answers on this one. Though, unfortunately the general answer is *"nobody really knows"*. ;-)

Comment: If the students attends a Universität or Fachhochschule then you call them "Student" in German. If they are younger they are "Schüler".

Comment: One of the most important rules is: never use the female form in a negative context. For example, "Studenten und Studentinnen", but not "Verbrecher und Verbrecherinnen". #ironyoff.

Answer (score 63):

You are falling into the trap laid out carefully by German Gender Mainstreaming throughout the years.

**No, in German a noun does not have a gender. It has a *genus***. This genus is a purely grammatical property defined by tradition. By default, it has nothing to do with biological sex or sociological gender.

The word `der Student` is a masculine noun describing people who study *regardless* of their sex or gender. A group of these people is described by the plural form `die Studenten` *regardless* of their sexual or gender composition.

Use these!

Another example for the same effect:

> die Katze (gr. neuter): a cat, bio. male or female
>   der Kater (gr. male): a bio. male cat

Comment: If "The word der Student is a masculine noun describing people who study regardless of their sex or gender", what or who does "die Studentin" describe?

Comment: If you stand in front of a mixed male and female group of students and you just greet them with "Liebe Studenten, ...", you will make less friends than if you would have said "Liebe Studenten und Studentinnen,...".

Comment: @Robert: Actually the generally accepted form is "Liebe Studentinnen und Studenten".

Comment: @karoshi: Sprache ist nicht symetrisch. "Studentin" bezeichnet einen weiblichen Studenten, und nur einen weiblichen. Zwei, drei und 753 Äpfel sind auch immer Äpfel, nur der eine Apfel ist ein Sonderfall - wieso nicht für 0 Äpfel oder 2 auch eine eigene Form? "Wie kalt" oder "wie warm ist es draußen" kann man fragen, unabhängig ob man nun meint es sei wohl kalt oder warm. Aber niemand fragt "Wie langsam fährt das Auto" - immer nur "wie schnell". Sprache ist nicht symetrisch, d.h. für Gruppen, die nur aus Männern bestehen, gibt es keine eigenen Wörter (außer: Kardinäle).

Comment: I agree and disagree. + 10000 for the genus part. But I think that when it comes to people (Fahrer, Student, Arzt) the article may still be just grammatical but since the word is only appropriate for one gender the gender has a feedback on the genus and makes that sounds "genderized"... if that makes any sense :). So "ein Student" will be associated with a male by 99% of the population. Anyway, totally right... "die Studenten" is gender-neutral and the gender-mainstreaming gets on my nerves

Comment: +1 for "This genus is a purely grammatical property defined by tradition. By default, it has nothing to do with biological sex or sociological gender.". I suggest adding an example such as *die männliche Katze* or *die männliche Fliege* to illustrate the point.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper The best example imo is "das mädchen". This would mean that girls are not feminine but neutral.

Comment: @bodycountPP: I don't think that's a good example. The diminutive always overrides any genus of the base noun to neuter, so it could be argued that the basic form of *Mädchen* is feminine nonetheless. Moreover, despite the grammatical gender of the word *Mädchen*, it is grammatically acceptable to refer to a *Mädchen* both by the neuter and feminine pronouns, further blurring the issue.

Comment: @Toscho, although English has the word _genus_ it doesn’t mean the same as German _Genus_ ‘grammatisches Geschlecht’. A correct German translation of the former would be _Gattung_ and a correct English translation of the latter would be _gender_, whereas the anglicism _Gender_ in German is used exclusively for ‘soziales Geschlecht’. Your “answer” is just as prescriptive as you perceive political correct language to be. The pragmatic and empiric truth is that you’ll offend more people with generic _Studenten_ than with _Studierende_ or _Studis_.

Comment: Acatually nowadays the gerundium(? not too sure about the name for this actually) `studierende` is used as it can be used with either `der` or `die`. This is a common technique to comply with the gendering madness (as outlined by others already)

Comment: @Crissov Yes, you're right. My answer is prescriptive. Applied Grammar is never purely descriptive, as everybody *expects* certain grammatical rules to be adhered to. Grammar wouldn't work otherwise in communication situations: Imagine a population of two German speaking people living on an isolated island. One of them decides to use the Perfect for processes in the future. Descriptive Grammar – 50% of the population does this – is totally useless here.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper `das Mädchen` is a very good example. It explicitely shows, that grammatical genus is *not* defined by meaning but other things like the diminuitive status. The pronouns are no good argument as pronouns might refer to words (in this case grammatically neuter) or the people themselves (in this case biologically feminine).

Comment: @Toscho: *das Mädchen* is neuter only because it is a diminutive. It is based upon the feminine word *die Magd*. Hence, it can still be argued that generally, the grammatical genus of nouns is inherently linked to the gender of the described thing, unless overridden by a generic modification such as diminutive that imposes a particular genus on the modified noun. Therefore, I think *das Mädchen* is a bad example; nouns that describe something of one gender, but use a contrasting genus *without any modifications such as diminutive* such as *die männliche Dogge* can illustrate the point better.

Comment: @Toscho: As for pronouns, they can help further clarify the difference. In the case of *das Mädchen*, the issue is blurred because as a native speaker, I perceive a text like *Das Mädchen singt. Sie singt leise.* as correct. The word *Mädchen* is an exception because it allows the use of both neuter *and* feminine pronouns. Contrast this with diminutives of other nouns: *Das Männchen singt. Er singt leise.* sounds simply wrong, because *Männchen* is invariably a neuter word and needs to be referred to with *es* rather than *er*, irrespective of the fact that it is the diminutive of *der Mann*.

Comment: @Toscho: Likewise, *Die männliche Fliege fliegt. Er fliegt schnell.* sounds totally wrong, as opposed to the correct *Die männliche Fliege fliegt. Sie fliegt schnell.* So, in the second sentence, the feminine pronoun *sie* further highlights how an inherently male thing can have the grammatical genus neuter, thus underlining how gender and genus are unrelated.

Comment: @Toscho, so why is prescriptive feminist language not okay then? I can oppose it because I think grammar has to be descriptive, but you just lost any ground you had left. Furthermore, your “thought example” shows that you don’t understand how language works at all.

Comment: I keep it short and simple: I'm a native speaker and writer for a newspaper. Don't go for the "gender neutral" rubbish, it makes spoken language hard to understand and written texts hard to read. We don't use it at least in Switzerland. The very few ones who do so are making political statements. If that's your plan, go for it, but inform yourself what statement you make (e.g. you could also leave the gap instead of "StudentInnen" make it "Student_innen" for the transgenders...). Just saying: Be careful with it, in everyday's language it's completely insignificant

Comment: All comments should be merged to answers in case they are of any relevance. **Please avoid lengthy comment threads.** Thank you.

Comment: @PatricHartmann The [Swiss Bundeskanzlei guidelines booklet](http://www.bk.admin.ch/dokumentation/sprachen/04915/05313/index.html?lang=de) is one of the best of its kind, though not perfect. It’s been cited as often as copied and is a clear sign that Switzerland is not exempt of the tendency to consciously choose words and carefully form phrases in public speech and writing.

Comment: **Moderator's note: Please stop adding further comments here.**

Answer (score 17):

If you know the name, use the name. That’s the easy part.

You can often still get away with ‘generisches Maskulinum’, i.e. *Studenten*, but in a university setting, i.e. where you’d actually use *Student* and *Studentin* to refer to students (instead of *Schüler* and *Schülerin* ‘pupil’ in a school or most other courses), it’s becoming rather common to use *Studierende*.

Since that participle is a verb form used as a noun, it inflects just like an adjective (i.e. also by gender), which works well in definite singular *der Studierende* and *die Studierende*, but fails for indefinite singular *ein Studierende****r*** and *eine Studierende*. The plural is always fine.

Please note that such words – although used like nouns – do **not** bear inherent gender. That’s restricted to proper names and proper noun stems, which can be overruled by derivative morphemes (e.g. *die …+keit/+heit, der …+ling, das …+chen*).

In non-formal contexts, e.g. amongst students, short forms can be used – *Studi* in this case, plural *Studis*, which could come from either *Studenten/-innen* or *Studierende*. Alas, such *-i* words are not perfect either, because they have a slight tendency to distinguish gender, too, but with *+ne* instead of common *+in*: *?Studine* isn’t frequent (yet), but *Hiwine* (to *Hiwi*) you hear a lot already.

PS: *Studierende* is one of the red flags that reliably spawn an emotional discussion of the merits of exactly the thing you want to do, i.e. gender-neutral or gender-aware language which results in conscious word and grammar choices that may feel unusual.

Comment: "Der Studierende" funktioniert auch nicht im Singular, wenn ein Artikel gebraucht wird. Außerdem bedeutet Studierender etwas anderes als Student, untergräbt also die Sprache und den richtigen Gebrauch des Infinitiv. Es gibt ein Rumgetrickse und RUmgeeiere, weil man den politischen Konflikt scheut der darin bestünde die Sprache richtig zu benutzen, statt einer Propagandabehauptung von der Unsichtbarmachung von Frauen sich blindlings zu ergeben.

Comment: _Studierende_ funktioniert insofern im Singular, dass nur noch der Artikel differenziert werden muss, also _der/die Studierende_, aber _der Student / die Studentin_ oder _der/die Student/-in_ und _ein Studierender / eine Studierende_ oder _ein(e) Studierende(r)_ etc.pp. Natürlich bedeutet _Studierender_ im Sprachgebrauch nahezu dasselbe wie _Student_, nur die Konnotationen sind andere. Sprachlich richtig ist, was die Mehrheit stillschweigend akzeptiert, d.h. nicht als falsch bemerkt. Ich vermeide substantivierte Partizipien meistens, weil sie auf mich gestelzt klingen – aber nicht falsch.

Comment: +1 für "Studierende", weil es, soweit ich weiß, ein sehr guter und wie du in deiner Selbst-Antwort ausführst geschlechtsneutraler Begriff ist. Es ist nicht wie bei "Konfirmanden" anstatt dem häufig gebraucht "Konfirmierten", denn man ist erst nach der Konfimation konfirmiert, aber vorher ist man "Konfirmant". Natürlich ist "Studenten" als Plural in Ordnung für gemischte Gruppen und "Studenten und Studentinnen" auch, aber "Studierende" spricht beide Geschlechter gleichermaßen an, ohne so langatmig zu klingen wie bei der zweiten Lösung.

Comment: Student spricht beide Geschlechter an, nur scheint man einer werden zu dürfen, ohne das kapieren zu müssen, sprich, heute bekommt man als funktionaler Analphabet der sich aus politischen Gründen, besser gesagt dem gutem, altem, deutschen Opportunimus ein bisschen doof stellt die allgemeine Hochschulreife. Wenn beim Artikel des Begriffs "der Studierende" doch differnziert werden muss, dann ist der Begriff auch nicht geschlechtsneutral. Vor allem aber wird der Begriff des Studierenden, wie er früher verstanden wurde, sabotiert. Dafür gibt es dann heute kein Wort mehr.

Comment: @userunknown, siehe [„Langlebige Studierende“ im Sprachlog](http://www.sprachlog.de/2011/11/18/langlebige-studierende/), auch wenn ich A. Stefanowitsch nicht immer und nicht in allen Punkten zustimme.

Comment: A. Stefanowitsch steht ja nicht nur, aber auch wegen seiner Aussagen in dieser Sache in Kritik. Ich empfehle stattdessen Belles Lettres, einmal einen Aufsatz des Betreibers an anderer Stelle als PDF:  http://www.klett-cotta.de/ausgabe/MERKUR_Heft_06_Juni_2014/49398?bereich_subnavi=zusammenfassung&artikel_id=50130 und einmal das Video http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/der-oder-das-blog_genus.php . Im Video geht es auch explizit um Anatol S.

Answer (score 12):

The noun has its own Genus. For "Student" it's masculinum, so you should use masculinum.

- Der Student is "the student" - both male and female
- Die Studentin is "the female student" - only female

In Indoeuropean languages, genus is the property of the noun, and there is only one "correct" grammar gender to refer to that noun.

English is a special case, where that concept is reduced. The nouns has no genus, a dog, for example, can be "he", "she" or "it". There are some exceptions, like "waitress" or "actress", but they are not commonly used nowadays.

There are artificial attempts in German to introduce pseudo-gender-neutral nouns like "Studierenden" but they are only pseudo-gender-neutral. In Singular, you have "der Studierende" or "die Studierende". Another problem is, that semantically, they have similar role to adjectives, so the constructs like "ehemalige Studierenden" makes not much sense. People also don't like when someone regulates what words should be used.

Answer (score 6):

Edit: being a bit older than 10 years ago, and hopefully not quite as dumb as I was 10 years ago, I have to revise that question. The old dumb version can still be found in the edit history.

Lets start with a bit of language history.

In old German, the grammatic gender was symmetrical. Words ending in -o were male, -a was female and if the ending was left out, it was neutral.

But then a vowel shift occurred that turned both -o and -a into -e, which then turned into -er. So there was basically no gender in the language anymore. The -er at the end of a word did not denote any gender.

So to be able to differentiate, the -in form was introduced, which allowed to specify that someone was female. But there is, to this day, no real male form in the German language.

If you are talking about a group of students who are all female, you can just say "die Studentinnen", but if you want to do the same for a male-only group, saying "die Studenten" is not enough, because it could still include women. Instead you have to workaround and say something like "die männlichen Studenten".

This concept is called "the generic masculinum" and it denotes that the generic form is at the same time the male form.

There are quite a few people who are unhappy with this form, since they feel that it's weird to call women by the male form.

So they try to split the generic form from the male form, by introducing different forms of gendering.

There are for example the Binnen-I (StudentInnen), the gender gap (Student_innen) or the gender asterisk (Student*innen).

These forms try to unite the male and female form in this new form. While the Binnen-I form is by now mostly accepted in the written form, both the gap and the asterisk are mostly used by people who see the Binnen-I as too weak/uninclusive towards non-binary people.

An issue with all of these forms is that it's rather hard to pronounce them in spoken language.

Older and widely accepted forms of gendering are "Studentinnen und Studenten" or "Bäcker/-innen". The last form only works in written language and only for words, where the female form is actually the male/generic form plus -innen.

So it wouldn't work for "Student/-innen", because the male/generic form is "Studenten" and not "Student".

A newer and widely acceptable form is to use a form of the word that is inherently gender neutral, e.g. "Studierende", which is identical in it's male and female form.

This topic is a politically charged one.

Many people on the left do gender, some don't, but generally, for the left this is a topic that was dealt with.

People on the right on the other hand are quite obsessed with dictating how other people are supposed to speak and many even go as far as boycotting media that uses gendering or even want to legally ban people from gendering.

If you want to be sure that nobody objects to what you are doing, use "Studentinnen und Studenten" (female form always comes first).

You can also use the Binnen-I or the "Studierende" form and only far right people might be offended by that, but most sane people will be fine with it.

If you want to make a political statement, use the gap or asterisk, but that could annoy a few more people.

All in all, I'd really wish they would have left the current generic/male version generic and split of the male version into a new non-generic male version.

Answer (score 5):

In German we often use the male form of the job titles although we don't mean explicitely one gender (ein Student). In plural this is used really often (Studenten). But both uses depend on the context. You can use it this way if it's a general statement. If you refer to certain people then use exact expressions. In the ages of feminism there came a few alternatives to this. You will find "Student/Studentin", "Student/in" or "StudentInnen" (the upper I shows that you mean both genders, but this is the feminism Version).
There are also examples where we use the female version although it could include male persons too (e.g. Putzfrau). [Here](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geschlechtergerechte_Sprache) you'll find more to that topic.

Answer (score 5):

Often for large groups of people of unknown or mixed gender the plural of the masculine form is used: "die Studenten" etc. This is known as the "Generisches Maskulinum". Of course, just using the masculine form is problematic as it ignores the women and there is an ongoing discussion about what a better alternative should be.

Also often used, especially when talking to them directly is using both, the plural of the masculine and feminine form: "Liebe Studenten und Studentinnen, ..."
But always referring to both forms makes some kinds of texts hard to read (e.g. a legal texts): "Dem Studenten / der Studentin wird für die Prüfung ein Prüfer / eine Prüferin zugewiesen, der/die den Studenten / die Studentin über das Fach prüft."
There are alternatives to shorten this, one for example is the "Binnen-I": "Dem/der StudentIn wird für die Prüfung ein/eine PrüferIn zugewiesen, der/die den/die StudentIn..." "Liebe StudentInnen" etc.
Other possible forms are the "Gender Gap" (yes, the english term is used in german, that's why it has the capital G, see [http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_Gap_(Linguistik)](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_Gap_%28Linguistik%29) ): "Student_in" or even combined: "Student_In".

There is not one standard way to use now as there are many arguments pro and con each way (see for example the arguments on the Binnen-I wikipedia page: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binnen-I ).

There are even more options than the ones described: Other, but very rare suggestions include just using the feminine form or switching between pure feminine and pure masculine forms between paragraphs.

So sadly, there is not one way to go but multiple alternatives to choose from and you will always find some people who don't like the way you have chosen... Trying to include everyone and not using the generic masculine is the best way to go as long as the text stays readable.

Most of this is also true when referring to one specific individual but when you address him or her directly (e.g. in a eMail), you should probably try to not use any pronouns and go by the name "Hallo Robin Meyer..." instead of "Liebe Robin Meyer" or "Lieber Robin Meyer" (Robin is a male name most of the time in germany, but you might expect a woman as you would think of Robin Scherbatsky from HIMYM...).

Answer (score 2):

Why the fuss? The OP **LITERALLY** asked "how do Germans refer to people without caring about the gender?" and everybody is breaking out into philosophy/linguistics/emancipation...

Just say

> Hi Leute! (hi people / hi guys)

If you want to say something about a person whose sex you don't know (for example they've sent you an email), just say

> Er oder sie hat mir 'ne Email geschrieben. Sorry, ich weiß nicht ob das ein männlicher oder weiblicher name ist.

If you smile apologetically and make it obvious that you're not maliciously trying to challenge anybody's gender identity or whatever you will never run into serious problems.

Just, you know, relax :) It's natural language. It's not like talking to a computer, where forgetting a semicolon will result in carnage.

Comment: No, the question was if there happens to be some gender-neutral noun for the plural to refer to mixed-gender groups, not what alternative words can be used.

Comment: Quoting: "How do Germans refer to people without caring about the gender(?)", "What should I say or write?".

Answer (score 2):

Neutral and modern: 'Sehr geehrte *Studierende*'

Comment: Das wirft aber genau dasselbe Problem auf. Im Singular ist »der Studierende« ebenso maskulin wie »der Student«. Auch der Plural ist maskulin, nur fällt das nicht auf. Außerdem klingt das Wort krankhaft konstruiert, ähnlich wie wenn ein Politiker bei einer Rede in einer Fabrik die Arbeiter mit »sehr geehrter Arbeitende« ansprechen würde. Oder falls er in einer Brotfabrik ist: »sehr geehrter Backende« (statt »Bäcker«). Jemand, der andere unterrichtet ist ein Lehrer, kein Lehrender. Jemand der Wände ausmalt it ein Maler, kein Malender. Warum sollte man also aus Studenten Studierende machen?

Comment: 'Student' ist lateinischer Herkunft und heißt 'Studierender' (PPA) ;)

Comment: Das "Studierende" hat eine gewisse Verbreitung, ist aber schlicht *faktisch falsch*. Die -ende Endung indiziert eine aktuelle Tätigkeit, wie das -ing im Englischen. Studierende sind Menschen, die gerade etwas studieren. Nicht alle Studierenden sind Studenten und nicht alle Studenten sind Studierende.

Answer (score 1):

**Proper** german makes a difference between *sexus* and *genus* - the biological and the grammatical gender of things. They have **very little in common** and the grammatical gender is **not** an indication of biological gender.

For example: *Der Manager* (male) and *Die Führungskraft* (female) are both gender-neutral descriptions of the same person (your boss).

**However**, there is a political movement that doesn't understand this and is very strong, especially around academia. It insinuates that these two unrelated things actually are related and the *generisches masculinum* (generic male form) is oppressive male chauvinism (ignoring the question what the generic female and neutral forms are, which also exist).

**If** you converse with those circles, as seems the case, you can research the artificial forms they have developed, which usually tack an "In" (a common, but not universal indicator of the female form) unto a generic male (and sometimes other) word. For example, "Student" becomes "StudentIn". Unfortunately, there is no common way in which to tack on this suffix, because just adding it in proper german writing would simply turn the male "Student" into the female "Studentin". One form is the one I gave: The "Binnen-I" - a capital I inside the word. Others are "Student/in" or "Student*in" and I'm sure there are yet more. All of them will be marked as wrong in your spellchecker, but here we are.

Note that if you add an article, it becomes "der/die Student/in". Or whatever butchered sentence someone feels correctly expresses their gender-political position.

For some common words, new words have been created, for example "die Studierenden" (plural form of students, literally meaning "those who are studying".

For plural, pick whichever you like best:

- Studenten (correct German, but it could be gender-political suicide)
- Studenten and Studentinnen (explicitly naming both genders)
- Studierende
- StudentInnen
- Student/innen
- Student*innen

Yes, it makes an already difficult language even more so. I don't recommend you express your thanks publicly in a university unless you want to not work there anymore.

Answer (score 1):

German is a mess right now with regards to "gender" or "sex."

The roots are in the supposedly "Frauenfeindliche Sprache" where so many nouns that refer to professions are masculine gendered words.  (But not all, siehe *die Lehrkraft*).

But the "corrective" action that is being taken, aside corrupting the original language, is going in the wrong direction: it is emphasizing and recommending a MORE BINARY approach, which is not actually more inclusive at all, instead reads rather hetero-normative.  Ask any LGBTQ+ person.

I propose the solution is to dial back and start using the words traditionally again, where a masculine gendered word is understood to refer to both sexes (or any sex, or no sex at all, I nod to the LGBTQ+ community).

Finally, I thought that the plural forms of German nouns have no gender at all (even in grammatical constructions), so I don't understand the trouble to which public speakers go, to address both sexes with separate *plural* words.  It does make for some very cumbersome speech.

Below I add a few words where I ask, what is the "feminine" form?  I've not heard it yet (as of Sept. 14, 2021):

- Der Gast, die Gästin?

And derivatives:

- Fahrgast
- Reisegäste
- Hausgäste
- etc.

Der Mensch
Der Suchende (e.g. Schutzsuchende)
Die Einsatzkraft
Die Lehrkraft (instead of der Lehrer!)  Can men not be referred to as "die Lehrkraft?"  (NO!  They would feel so emasculated!)
Der Unternehmer (in recent TV "Trielle" Amin laschet failed to address Unternehmerinnen!)

For a moment I theorized that only nouns ending in "er" are victims of the linguistic gender war (i.e. Lehrerin, Bürgerin, ...), but on dradio.de have noticed Hörer used without a corresponding feminine gender (they do not acknowledge the existence of any Hörerinnen).   Or what about Fahrer, like "Busfahrer"?  Is there a feminine ever used (Busfahrerin)?

Also, I notice that when such a "personal noun" is part of a compound noun, the effort to include the feminine is abandoned.  For example:

Korrespondentennetzwerk. (What of Korrespondentinnennetzwerk?)
I suppose the female(s) cannot be included because the actual noun is "Netzwerk" - which has no female version... but then it also implies there are no female members as part of the "Netzwerk" - how can one reconcile this "sexist" output?

In sum: a mess.

I don't know the solution.

Comment: Is that an answer or a long comment?

Comment: Es ist nicht an Berufe gebunden, siehe Fußgängerampel, NIchtschwimmerbecker, Schläfer, Träumer, Brite, Esser, Verbrecher, Christ, ...

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a pretty easy thing. But people are overstating both the degree to which grammatical gender and biological gender are separated in German and also how hotly political it is.

So here is an actually practical answer that actually answers the question how it was likely intended, minus prescriptive grammar and political polemics.

I will start with some context because of the rest of the answers, but if you don't care, just skip to the bold **"BUT"**, below, and then read only until you get bored.

There is ambiguity. Grammatical gender in German is only partially distinct from biological gender, in that in mainstream use people often both use the grammatical gender to imply a biological gender or understand it as an intention of the speaker to denote a gender. Since language is an inherently cooperative activity, this cannot be ignored if one wishes to understand or be understood correctly. While it is true that the grammatical gender usually does not technically specify a biological gender, that ignores how the language is used by the vast majority of people everyday.

Fact is in the lived experience of a non native speaker: if there are multiple gendered words, the majority of people **will** correct you if you use the one that doesn't correspond to the gender of the person or thing you are referring to even if it isn't linguistically necessary. This demonstrates that at the very least, grammatically gendered words carry a connotation of biological gender both historically and in mainstream practice.

There are multiple ways of dealing with this that have not really achieved consensus, and new ways being invented all the time. Some of this is slightly politically charged, but not to the "culture war" levels that some of the answers seem to suggest.

**BUT** the everyday reality is that there are only really three (broad) ways to do this:

- List both gendered words explicitly (with or without some form of abbreviation)
- Use only one word (and either explicitly mention you mean both, or ignore the problem and potentially be misunderstood in a way that you might not have intended)
- Use an adjectival noun derived from a verb for gender neutral plurals

**In the real world (almost exclusively):**

Academic works usually follow the second approach, and often include a disclaimer once at the beginning that no gender implication is intended. (i.e. Student)

Job postings use all approaches. If the second approach is used it is almost always accompanied by a parenthetical (m/w) or something similar. (i.e. Student (m/w), Student/-in)

Every day usage is almost 100% the first approach or the third approach. (Studenten und Studentinnen, or Studierende)

There is almost never a practical need for a gender neutral singular. It just doesn't really come up that often, but the easiest default is the first approach (Student oder Studentin), since unambiguous use of the second approach is context/audience dependent and you have to be able to read the room to know if doing that without explicitly mentioning is a problem or not.

I know for example, that if I personally ask my boss about internship applications from "Studenten", that they know I mean all applicants. In other contexts (especially if I don't personally know the person) I might choose to explicitly mention both alternatives, because communication with strangers is inherently more ambiguous if you haven't yet established a rapport. Like anything in language, context is important. If you are in a situation where you are confused as to the appropriate word to use, usually the best course of action is to actually express that confusion explicitly.

If I had to guess, the reason for the high insistance that this is extremely political comes from people who alternatively:

- can't read the room
- have very prescriptive notions of language
- or think the various abbreviations look stupid or are cumbersome

Yes if you fall into one of those categories, you are going to have a hard time.

And generally unless you fall into one of those categories yourself, whatever you decide to do will be fine with 95% of the German speaking population, and the people you do piss off will likely be in one of those categories.

**And if you do actually step into a Fettnäpfchen, people tend to be forgiving as long as it isn't on social media. Even then, most of the time backlash is based on how people respond to being "called-out" and not to the original (perceived) offense. If you respond to criticism like a tone-deaf idiot, people are likely to assume you are a tone-deaf idiot.**

For context, I have lived for over 10 years in the German speaking world and over 20 years before that in America without ever even once attempting to be explicitly "politically correct", and literally never once had a problem. If you act like a nice, respectful person people will generally treat you like one.

Comment: nice answer! (+1 für Fettnäpfchen)

Comment: this part "a parenthetical (m/w) " is nowadays changed to "a parenthetical (m/w/d)" since the BVerfG ruled out that there are more then two. Well, technically it did not rule it out since the BVerfG does not write any law.

Comment: Da stimmt vieles nicht. Natürlich braucht man oft einen unspezifischen Singular, und der ist fast immer maskulin ("Ich brauch einen Arzt!") und dann hat man auch keine Wahlfreiheit. Ausnahmen: Person, Koryphäe, Fachkraft, Mitglied. Hitorisch ist die behauptete Geschlechtskonnotation nicht, siehe Fußgängerampel, Nichtschwimmerbecken und Katzenfutter. Merkwürdigerweise kommt man bei unerfreulichen Personen auch meist gut ohne Gendern aus: "Die Täter sind flüchtig" oder "Vor Betrügern wird  gewarnt." Die Formen "Studierende" etc. sind auch moderne Schöpfungen; früher abweichend benutzt.

Comment: @userunknown Erstens: zuseammengesetzte Wörter funktionieren anders in dieser Hinsicht. Die originale Frage geht nicht um zusammengesetzte Wörter, also ist das irrelevant. Zweitens: ja es gibt natürlich Gegenbeispiele zu allem was ich behauptet habe. ABER fast jede andere Anwort war entweder "Duden sagt der Maskulin form ist generisch, also scheiß drauf was andere leute denken", oder eine Tirade über Political Correctness. Beides ist nicht wahr, und weder das eine noch das andere ist eine praktische Hilfe für jemand dessen Muttersprache kein Genus hat.

Comment: Zusammengesetzte Wörter funktionieren nicht anders in dieser Hinsicht - das ist Wunschdenken. Dann hätte ich gerne einen Beleg dafür, dass der Dugen sagt "scheiß drauf" - das entspricht nicht dem Sprachgebrauch, den man vom Duden gewohnt ist. Wenn die generische Form nun mal maskulin ist (außer bei Gast, Mitglied, Person usw.) - was soll der Duden machen? Verletzte Seelen trösten, von Leuten, die mit der Realität nicht zurecht kommen? Und ins Physikbuch schreiben wir nettes für Flatearthler und ins Biobuch die Schöpfungsgeschichte der Bibel?

Comment: Wenn vor der Frauenbibliothek ein Schild stünde "Studenten ist der Zutritt untersagt" - würde das das gleiche bedeuten wie "männlichen Studenten ist der Zutritt untersagt"?

Comment: @userunknown Ich habe nicht gesagt "Duden sagt scheiß drauf". Ich kann aber verstehen wie der Satzbau zu diesem Irrtum leitet. Manche leute lesen ein Grammatikbuch wie ein Gesetztbuch und nehmen was es sagt als Beweis dafür, dass leute die es nicht genau verfolgen "falsch" legen. Mein Punkt war, Sprache funktioniert nicht so. Die allermeiste in Deutschland verwenden die Sprache nicht wie es im Lehrbuch steht, also wenn einer mit echten Menschen kommunizieren möchte ist es egal was im Lehrbuch dann steht.

Comment: @userunknown Gegenfrage zu deiner: wenn in einem Supermarkt ein Schild stehen würde "Sonderangebot: Tomaten", würde das das gleiche bedeuten wie "Sonderangebot: giftfreie Tomaten"?

Comment: Ich weiß nicht, in Biosupermärkten würde mich ein solches Schild nicht sonderlich überraschen, aber ich weiß, dass Tomaten von Natur aus Niccotin enthalten, am Strunk und im Blattwerk. Was soll denn meine Reaktion jetzt zeigen? Dass alle Studenten männlich sind? Das ist eine moderne Erscheinung, dass behauptet wird, weil es das Wort "Studentin" für weibliche Studenten gibt müsse "Student" - aus einer Art Symmetrie, die aber nun mal kein Gesetz der Grammatik ist - männliche Studenten bezeichnen. ...

Comment: ... Wenn Du ältere Texte bis in die 80er Jahre liest wirst Du feststellen, dass diese selbstverständlich die männliche Form benutzt haben, auch wenn klar beide Geschlechter gemeint waren. Erst ganz allmählich hat sich aus feministischen Milieus heraus dieses absichtliche Falschverstehen der Sprache entwickelt. Das mussten sich die Leute erst willentlich selbst beibringen. Trotzdem sagt man auch heute noch "Jemand hat seine Handtasche vergessen, trotz größter Wahrscheinlichkeit, dass es eine Frau war". Du schuldest noch die Erklärung, inwiefern u. wieso zs.-gesetzte Wörter anders funktionieren.

Comment: @userunknown I don't owe you a thing. If you know so much better then write your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Students (and of course all sexually reproducing creatures) don't have genders, they have *sexes* (male and female are different *sexes*; masculine and feminine *nouns* are different genders). The word you want is *Studenten*, which refers to both sexes, male and female, collectively. It is the plural form of both *die Studentin* and *der Student*. Otherwise, when referring to a single student, you have to use *der Student* if you *don't* know the sex of the student, and *die Studentin* if you *do* know that the student is female.

Comment: Every human has both a sex and a gender.

Answer (score -3):

Correct German has a single plural form, which is "die Studenten".

Sadly, there exist some political groups which want political speech such as "Neusprech" in George Orwell's 1984, however, their German is not correct German, and their attitude stems from a complete misunderstanding of language in general and German language in particular.

"Die Studenten" is the correct plural form including everything and everybody!

Comment: Hi ASlateff! Your answer makes a claim about what is correct in German. The topic of gender neutral language is highly debated amongst speakers of German, and your answer fails to address this fact. Please have a look at this thread on Meta: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1340/wie-k%c3%b6nnen-wir-den-themenbereich-um-geschlechtergerechte-sprache-objektiv-halten

Answer (score -9):

The correct term would probably be "das Student" (genderneutral) .. but german tradition forbids you to use it. Would be nice to see "das" used as the english "the".

Comment: This has been proposed indeed, e.g. by infamous Luise Pusch, but mostly in the 1970s and 1980s, often alongside an artificial male counterpart to _+in_. Low German (_Plattdeutsch_) has articles _dat_ (n) and _de_ (c), instead of _die_ (f) and _der_ (m). Some urban sociolects actually use _da_, as in http://daStandard.at

Comment: Using "das" isn't like using "the" but like using "it". Using "it" towards a person is as disrespectful in German as it is in English. A comparable situation in English would be that you also don't use "it" for someone whose gender you don't know (e.g. if you talk about some company representative you only wrote to using their customer service mail address it would be very derogatory to call that person "it").

Comment: @Dakkaron, it’s also been proposed for English to use _it_ where you’re unsure whether _he_ or _she_ was correct. Currently, singular _they_ is the most promising candidate to take that job.

Comment: That's the way I know it aswell, using "they" in singular for a person of unknown sex.

Comment: This is **not** a correct answer. It's a misunderstanding of German grammar, which does **not** allow you to simply switch out the grammatical gender of a word. It's not german tradition that forbids this, it's german language.