# Gender-neutral phrasing of "a cook"?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, usage

> We are looking for a cook for the restaurant.
>
> Wir suchen einen Koch / eine Köchin für das Restaurant.

Is there a more elegant way to phrase this? The part "einen Koch / eine Köchin" seems cumbersome and awkward. However, we need to specify that we want either a male or a female cook, and since they go with different articles, it seems that we need to phrase it this way.

Comment: Als Phrase hat sich das in der Tat eingebürgert, obwohl "Wir suchen einen Koch" eine generelle Suche nach einer Person, die ein Koch ist, ausdrückt, und kein Geschlecht festlegt.

Comment: If this is an ad in a paper or a website or similar, something like "Wir suchen einen Koch (m/w)" is sometimes used.

Comment: Consider the legal obligation to be gender-neutral when hiring. So you will **have to** use this cumbersome phrasing or add "(m/w)" to the male/neutral form. Does it sound elegant? Heck, no, but....

Comment: related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/13735/how-do-germans-refer-to-people-without-caring-about-the-gender

Comment: _Küchenpersonal in Leitungsfunktion mit abgeschlossener Kochausbildung oder mehrjähriger professioneller Kocherfahrung_ – here _koch_ comes or at least may come from _kochen_ ‘to cook’, not from _Koch/Köchin_ ‘cook’.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could also use "einen Koch (m/w)".

Comment: This is actually quite common in advertising.

Comment: You're right, I forgot about that.

Answer (score 3):

You can either use

```
einen Koch / eine Köchin
```

or

```
eine(n) Koch / Köchin
```

but "einen Koch / eine Köchin" seems best to me.

Answer (score 0):

another option would be:

```
Koch/Köchin für deutsche Küche in Berlin gesucht
```

for sure city and german culinary were just examples and should be adapted.